# Web notifications subscribers data - endpoint - send notifications

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, web-push, web-notifications

I'm trying to understand how web notification(HTML5) is works.

I found some solutions for call user for permissions:[notify.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js),

currently I am looking for any way to send notifications for subscribed users. I planing to create a backend script in PHP. What kind of data, should I save when user allows notifications receiving, for easy sending notifications?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of web notifications:

- *on-site* push notifications: you can send them only when a user has a page of your website open. You can use the **Web Notification API** (or notify.js) to display the notification. You also need to fetch the notification from a server: you can use *AJAX*, *long polling*, *websockets*, etc.
- *off-site* push notifications: you can reach a user even when he is not on your website. You need to use the **Web Notification API** together with the **W3C Push API** and **service workers**. In this case you need to collect an *endpoint* that represents the user device (browser), then store it on a server and then send notifications to it (for example using [this PHP library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)). Otherwise you can use a service like [Pushpad](https://pushpad.xyz) (I am the founder) which offers a PHP library.

Comment: What is endpoint, is it any ID what returns browser after subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is a URL with a secret token that the application server can use to POST notifications to that browser.

Comment: I can't understand :( Can you describe step by step how it's works? How to call browser for endpoint and other data?

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your relationship with PushPad! It is appreciated.